# Gremlingo: Traverser does not map to value when adding edge between two vertices

Tags: go, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I am using tinkerpop [gremling-go](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/tree/master/gremlin-go) to access gremlin-server/JanusGraph. When trying to create an edge between two vertices, I get the following error

```
The provided traverser does not map to a value: ...
```

Vertices are added via

```
t.AddV("somenode").Property("some_id", someID).Iterate()
```

and

```
t.AddV("someothernode").Property("some_id", someID).Iterate()
```

where `t` is `*gremlingo.GraphTraversal`. Vertices are added successfully.

Edge is added via

```
t.AddE("someedge").
        From(
            __.V().
                HasLabel("somenode").
                Has("some_id", someID),
        ).
        To(
            __.V().
                HasLabel("someothernode").
                Has("some_id", someID),
        ).
        Iterate()
```

where again `t` is `*gremlingo.GraphTraversal` and `__` is alias for `gremlingo.T__`. Edge is not created with error output above.

Using gremlin-console adding edge via `g.addE("someedge").from(__.V().hasLabel("somenode").has("some_id","some_id_1")).to(__.V().hasLabel("someothernode").has("some_id","some_id_1"))` where `g` is the traversal works just fine.

Note that I left out go error handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you wait for async request completion?

`channel := t.AddV("somenode").Property("some_id", someID).Iterate()`

`err := <-channel`

Comment: Yes, I did. Queries and the example are fine. Got something wrong apart from gremlingo. Will count your answer as correct:)